# Change two select box option according to each other by it's index in jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have two Selectbox like this

```
<select id="emp">
    <option value="emp1"> Emp Name 1</option>
    <option value="emp2"> Emp Name 2</option>
    <option value="emp3"> Emp Name 3</option>
    <option value="emp4"> Emp Name 4</option>
</select>


<select id="salary">
    <option value="sal1"> $1000</option>
    <option value="sal2"> $2000</option>
    <option value="sal3"> $3000</option>
    <option value="sal4"> $4000</option>
</select>
```

Here both selectbox have same no of options. Now if anyone select **$3000** from **salary selectbox**, the **emp selectbox** will be automaticaly selected the value **"Emp Name 3"** or anyone select a value i.e **"Emp Name 2"** from **emp selectbox** then **salary selectbox** will be automaticaly selected the value **$2000**. But the problem is I can't understand how to do it. So if anyone have any idea about that please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is use the `selectedIndex` property of `<select>`. Within a change handler get the current value and assign to the other select

```js
var $selects = $('#emp, #salary').on('change', function(){
   $selects.not(this).prop('selectedIndex', this.selectedIndex)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="emp">
    <option value="emp1"> Emp Name 1</option>
    <option value="emp2"> Emp Name 2</option>
    <option value="emp3"> Emp Name 3</option>
    <option value="emp4"> Emp Name 4</option>
</select>


<select id="salary">
    <option value="sal1"> $1000</option>
    <option value="sal2"> $2000</option>
    <option value="sal3"> $3000</option>
    <option value="sal4"> $4000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this by getting the index of the selected option when the select element change and then changing the option in the other select element.

Here is the code:

```
$('#emp').on("change", function(){
 var index = $('#emp')[0].selectedIndex;

 $("#salary").prop('selectedIndex', index);
})

$('#salary').on("change", function(){
 var index = $('#salary')[0].selectedIndex;

 $("#emp").prop('selectedIndex', index);
})
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arz1wmLj/4/